# Count the total number of the characters

Tags: java

if I have the following 2D object of `char` type:

```
aaaa...||
bbb..|ccc
ddddd..|d
```

the method `countChars()` returns the number of the letters which are different, i.e. in the example above the result returned is `4` because there are `a,b,c,` and `d` characters. It does not count every single character (`'.'` and `'|'` are not included while counting) but counts the number of different characters in the array. Another example:

```
zzz.zz||
....tt|.
wwwwwwww
```

The above result returned by the method is `3` (`z`, `t` and `w`)
In my code, I'm not getting the desired result.

```
 public int countChars()
        {
            char originalChar = 0;
            char anotherChar = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for(int r = 0; r < height; r++)
            {
                for(int c = 0; c < width; c++)
                {
                    if(space[r][c] != '.' || space[r][c] != '|')
                    {
                        space[r][c] = originalChar;
                    }
                    count++;
                    space[r][c] = originalChar;
                }

            }

            return count;
        }
```

Comment: firstly in  `if(space[r][c] != '.' || space[r][c] != '|')` should be `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: @John Does your problem forbid you from using Java collections of any sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `Set` to handle this problem, since it eliminates the problem of counting duplicates.

```
public int countChars() {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();

    for (int r = 0; r < height; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < width; ++c) {
            if (space[r][c] != '.' && space[r][c] != '|') {
                set.add(new Character(space[r][c]));
            }
        }
    }

    return set.size();
}
```

This solution assumes that `.` and `|` are the only two characters which you want to exclude.  If you had it in mind to count only letters (or letters and numbers) then please update your problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to loop every single chars in the loop without even checking if they are already counted:

what you need to do is to create an array that will hold the already counted char:

sample below is without using any Collections framework.

```
public int countChars()
        {
            char originalChar = 0;
            char anotherChar = 0;
            int count = 0;
            char [] countedChar = new char[255] //max char array
            for(int r = 0; r < height; r++)
            {
                for(int c = 0; c < width; c++)
                {
                    if(space[r][c] != '.' || space[r][c] != '|')
                    {
                        space[r][c] = originalChar;
                        continue; 
                    }

                    if(countedChar[space[r][c]] != null) continue; //if char is already counted then continue;

                    countedChar[space[r][c]] = 's'; //add the index of the char array as the char number.

                    count++;
                    space[r][c] = originalChar;
                }

            }

            return count;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of characters to hold unique characters.  Each time you come to a char that is not a '.' or a '|' compare it to each character of the array, and if there is no match, add it to the array and increase your count. Here is some psudo code.

```
char[] uniqueChars = new char[26];
boolean unique = true;
int count = 0;
while(!at the end of the arrays){
    char c = next character in the arrays;
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
        if(uniqeChars[i]==c){
            unique = false
        }
    }
    if(unique){
        uniqueChars[count] = c;
        count++;
    }
    unique = true;
}
```